# Find and replace help, to remove certain things from text

Tags: text, replace, notepad++, notepad

I have file which contain 18k lines of text which consists of links and rondom ID codes and looks like this:

"

```
http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardNano
SC09661
http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardUno
http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1639172.pdf

SC09670
http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardUno
SC09665
http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoEthernetShield
SC09662
http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoXbeeShield
CS23020
http://bcove.me/zypzpy2q
SC09147
http://cache.national.com/ds/LM/LM134.pdf
SC08546
http://cache.national.com/ds/LM/LM2574.pdf
SC08540
http://cache.national.com/ds/LM/LM2576.pdf
```

"
I need to remove from this text all those ID codes (SC08540,SC09662,...) and links which not ends with .pdf, I know its posible with Notepad++ and other programs, with Replace funkction, but I dont know how exacly should I do this. Maybe I could get help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not found a way to do this in one go with Notepad++ but this should work:

- Open the replace box (`Search --> Replace...`) and select `Regular expression`
- Search for `^.*[^\.][^p][^d][^f]$`
- Make sure `Replace with` is empty
- `Replace All`

Now you have a file with empty lines and the links you want. There are at least two ways to get rid of the empty lines:

Method 1: **TextFX plugin**

- Select all text
- `TextFX --> TextFX Edit --> Delete blank lines`

Method 2: **Replace**

- Make sure the cursor is at the beginning of the document
- Open the replace box (`Search --> Replace...`) and select `Extended`
- Search for `\n\r`
- Make sure `Replace with` is empty
- `Replace All`